# JQuery check 'header' width onload

Tags: jquery, mobile, width, element, onload

I'm making my first **responsive website**. And as you know '**mobile first**'. Just started at the **320px** width version.

Can you help me with ***beginner*** code, on how to check the width of the header **onload**, without having to resize manually first.

This is what i have so far, it works... but only after resizing manually.
Need to get this to work straight away.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(){   
        if ($("header").width() <= 320 ){
            $(".link").on("mousedown", function() {
                $("header").animate({"top":"-15%"});
                $("nav").animate({"bottom":"-93%"});
                $("#return").css("display","inline-block");
            });
            $("#return").on("mousedown", function() {
                $("#return").css("display","none");
                $("header").animate({"top":"0%"});
                $("nav").animate({"bottom":"-15%"});
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: responsive designs are normally made in css, not in javascript. Using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: i do. but jQuery is easier for animations then css3. And better for cross-browser design.

Comment: @Klaus Byskov Pedersen, we can't just rely on css / css3 on responsive designs. In my case, I always use JQUERY in responsive design. Here's one of my work using jquery mobile responsive. [***Click here***](http://www.budgetshop.com.ph/).

Comment: Ok. If you don't want to wait for the user to resize the window, then just don't put your code in the `resize` event handler, e.g. remove `$(window).resize(function(){   ` and `});`. That would make your code run onload.

Comment: i tried it... the problem is when the width of the header becomes 480px, (simulating a rotation from portrait to landscape, 320x480px) the jquery code is still executed, when it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("header").innerWidth(); or $("header")..outerWidth();
```

to work the codes after load, use this.

```
$( window ).bind( 'load', function(){
    // codes
});
```

If your problem is on scroll ( UP / Down ) function, use this.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
    $(this).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
            // codes
        }
    });
} else {
    $(this).bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 < 1) {
               // codes            }
    });
}
```

On re-size function use this ..

```
$(window).resize(function(){   
    if (window.innerWidth < 321 ){
       // codes to be done in 320 below
    }else{
       // codes to be done in 320 above 
    }
});
```

Comment: almost there... the **if statement** seems to stay **true** even if the **width** of the **header** becomes **480px**. _Landscape mode_

Comment: I use FireFox Developer Edition for responsive design. It has a very usefull toggle for portrait and landscape mode in different phone and tablet sizes. Its when i simulate this flip from portait to landscape, that the if statement still seems to pass. Where it shouldn't.

Comment: I have [***responsive tool***](http://wptaskforce.com/responsive/1/) that i built for my mobile responsive. Try to use it bro. Can you give me the URl of your site? So I can help you this?

Comment: it's not online, yet.

Comment: Change the if statement to *if (window.innerWidth < 481 ){* instead of *if (window.innerWidth < 321 ){*. If this is not the correct answer then please create a **HTML / CSS / JQUERY** sample using http://fiddle.jshell.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. add jQuery mobile in the head.
2. And add above it, this script, to disable the 'loading' text at the bottom of your web page.

   ```
   <script>$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){$.mobile.loadingMessage =false;});</script>

   <script src="jq_lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   ```

   3. add browser refresh on 'orientationchange' to you 'jQuery code.

      ```
      $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function() {
          location.reload();
      });
      ```

the full code without step 1 & 2.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var ref = $("header").width();

        //refresh bij orientatie verandering.
        $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function() {
            location.reload();
        });

        //320x480 portrait
        if (ref <= 320 ){
            $(".link").on("mousedown", function() {
                $("header").animate({"top":"-15%"});
                $("nav").animate({"bottom":"-93%"});
                $("#return").css("display","inline-block");
            });
            $("#return").on("mousedown", function() {
                $("#return").css("display","none");
                $("header").animate({"top":"0%"});
                $("nav").animate({"bottom":"-15%"});
            });
        }

        //320x480 landscape
        if (ref >=321 && ref <= 480 ){
            $(".link").on("mousedown", function() {
                $("header").animate({"top":"-21%"});
                $("nav").animate({"bottom":"-90%"});
                $("#return").css("display","inline-block");
            });
            $("#return").on("mousedown", function() {
                $("#return").css("display","none");
                $("header").animate({"top":"0%"});
                $("nav").animate({"bottom":"-25%"});
            });
        }
});
```